# JavaScript closures and memory management

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-management, closures

I'm curious as to how memory is handled with variables inside closures. Take this code for example -

```
function iAmAClosure() {
    var txtName = document.getElementById('name');

    function validation() {
        if (txtName.value.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function () {
        return validation();
    }
}
```

My `validation` function is called whenever the user clicks on a button.

My question is, does the `txtName` variable stay in memory as long as the page is active, or is it GC'ed and initialized every time the method validation is called? Is there something more to it then that?

What's better performance wise?

Comment: closure doesn't matter, if the var is unreachable, it will be collected.

Comment: "performance" does depend on processing power vs. memory size. You cannot say which is better in general. But notice that to initialize it every time, you will need to explicitly move the code into your `validation` function - the behaviour is well defined.

Comment: @dandavis: That's just the reason why the closure does matter - it makes the variable reachable :)

Comment: im just saying that closure itself has no impact on collection these days. IE6 DID have some issues with enclosed event handlers, but that was a long time ago...

Comment: I also wonder about this in server environments like Node.  Consider [this stream example](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_consumers).  The `body` variable sticks around so long as the `end` and `data` event handlers are reachable.  As a Node newbie, I'm guessing the http module releases its references to these event handlers after the request completes, thus releasing the `body` closure variable.  Each request creates a new closure (through the function passed to `createServer`) and new event handlers.  But the doc does not say they do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any variables in the closure of a function are kept in memory as long as there is a way to reference that function. Here, `txtName` is in the closure of your `onclick` function, so it will stay in memory as long as the `onclick` binding is intact and the "submit" button exists.

Comment: Thanks. One last question - What would be your best educated guess as to how much memory I can use  before the page becomes slow? Also is the chrome dev tool the best too to test my memory usage?