# How closure retains the reference to parent function variables when parent function's execution context is removed from stack?

Tags: javascript

Consider below code :

```
function x () {
 let a=1;
 function y(){
  console.log(a)
 }
 return y
}

const d = x();
```

When `x` is executing, its execution context is on stack-top. In its execution context, `a` is defined (which means `a` remains on stack). When `x` finishes, its execution context is removed and this `a` also removed from stack. So how `y` retains the reference to `a` even after `x`'s execution context is removed from stack ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: maybe the activation records are not part of the stack

Comment: @Pointy what do you mean by activation records ?

Comment: it's an old term for "place where local variables are stored" when talking about function calls. In C, you're right, it's the stack. But it doesn't *have* to be the stack.

Comment: @Pointy So in javascript, all variables stored on heap ? or atleast the local function variables which are needed in closure are stored on heap ?

Comment: Well they're stored in a place that *works* like the heap, at least. The language spec describes the behavior, but an implementation is free to do things any way it wants, so long as programs work the way they are supposed to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614895/javascript-closures-and-memory-management#:~:text=Any%20variables%20in%20the%20closure,the%20%22submit%22%20button%20exists.

Comment: "*at least the local function variables which are needed in closure are stored on heap?*" - yes, precisely that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the referenced link does not answer my question. i also know closured variable stay in memory but I asked specifically where - stack or heap. which other comments have answered

Comment: @Pointy & Bergi My doubts is now exactly cleared that closured variable are not stored in stack even if they are primitive. they are stored on heap.

Only 2 links mentioned in duplicate-reporting of this question answers my question to some extent, other two does not answer anything related to stack and heap. But I am happy that my doubt get solved, so no issues if it got reported as duplicate.

Comment: @Yusuf it's not a bad thing for a question to be marked as a duplicate. Your version of the question may be very close to the concern some other person might have, tomorrow or a year from now, so it's still valuable as a way to get to the linked other questions.

Comment: @Pointy yes yes no issues in that & i am very happy that this version precisely and visually solved my doubt. thanks for that to you & Bergi